# Facebook Spring Boot login with OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm building a project with Spring Boot and Spring Security and I would like to implement the signup phase with Facebook and Google. I read about OAuth2 but I couldn't find any guide which shows exactly what to do in order to make a user sign up into my service using Facebook or Google.
I would like to have a reference inside my database which tells me that that particular user is signed up with facebook for example...
Right now I'm using Spring Security to handle the sign up and sign in phases and everything works fine.

This is the Configuration class

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

And this is the CustomUserDetails class which I suppose it must have also an attribute which tells how this user signup to my service (facebook, google, local etc.)

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    public CustomUserDetails() {
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(String username, String email, String password, Set<Role> roles) {
        super(username, email, password, roles);
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        super(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getRoles());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles()
                .stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In overview, to login by Facebook or Google, we have following steps:

1. User click on **Login by Facebook** or **Login by Google**
2. A popup is shown up and User click **Accept**.
3. User get an `access_token` from Facebook or Google and send it to you (Web Server)
4. Use user's `access_token` and verify it using **Google or Facebook API** and get user information.
5. If `access_token` is correct, you create user for it. You can user either token or session. If `access_token` is not correct, throw an `exception`.
6. Login success.

> Get more information about access_token:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! So what you are suggesting is to implement it without OAuth2 and Spring Security, did I get it right?

Comment: About OAuth2, yes. But you still need Spring Security to implement authentication using session or token.

Comment: I see! Can you explain why this way is better than using OAuth2?

Comment: It's not better than OAuth2 but I can easier to adapt when Facebook API is updated.